# my Mac Pro was stolen and had Adobe Master suite on it. is there a way to delete that program on the stolen lap top and install it on a new one?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

My Mac Pro was stolen...I still have the computer ID..can I delete the adobe CS on that computer so I can install it on a new MAC Pro?  I have the CS on my Mac Desk and I would like to install it on my new Mac Pro?

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually delete it on the computer that is gone.

The problem you may have is that Adobe CS requires product activation which ties the software to that particular computer.

Adobe allow you to activate CS on two computers so you should be fine to install on your new computer if it's not the third you've done, which from your question it seems it would be.

If you have already done it on two computers you will have to get Adobe to deactivate CS on the old computer. To do this phone Adobe Customer Support. There's no software way around this with the version of CS you have (people with a volume license don't have this problem.)

Check out the Activation FAQ :-

http://www.adobe.com/eeurope/activation/faq.html